# Данные затирают функцию

Tags: ассемблер

```
CODE    SEGMENT
    ASSUME CS:CODE,DS:NOTHING,ES:NOTHING,SS:NOTHING
    ORG ORIGIN


    Public $START
$START:
            ; WARNING -- Don't change this to a short jmp
    jmp Main            ; Jump to start of code


PUBLIC uData
uData   LABEL   BYTE
                        ;Equates to allow access to
                        ;storage where Main is now
Sec9        EQU BYTE PTR uData+0    ;11 byte diskette parm. table


MAIN:
    cli             ;Stop interrupts till stack ok
    xor AX,AX
    mov SS,AX           ;Work in stack just below this routine

;--------- skip code


    mov BX,78h
    lds SI,DWORD PTR SS:[BX]    ; get address of disk table
    push    DS          ; save original vector for possible
    push    SI          ; restore
    push    SS
    push    BX
    mov DI,OFFSET Sec9
    mov CX,11
    cld

    repz    movsb
```

Тут получается что когда мы доходим до movsb то там где раньше была функция Main на это место скопированы 11 байтов. Я новичек в ассемблере и хотел спросить- я правильно разобрался в коде, или тут ошибка? Правильно что функция Main затирается данными 11 байт?

Comment: Инструкция `rep movsb` копирует CX-байт из адреса `DS:SI` (источник) в `ES:DI` (приёмник). Вот и смотрите в отладчике, какие значения имеют у вас эти регистры.